# Extending setState to only run if mounted

Tags: flutter, widget, state

I'm trying to write an extension method to avoid issues with calling setState when a Widget isn't mounted. The code looks something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

extension SetStateIfMounted on State {
  void setStateIfMounted(VoidCallback onMounted, [ VoidCallback onNotMounted ]) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(onMounted);
    } else {
      LogService.logger.w('Widget not mounted. setState being ignored');
      if (onNotMounted != null)
        onNotMounted();
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a bad idea? Is there some reason I wouldn't always want to check if a widget is mounted before calling setState()?

Comment: Why not just let the exception break out from this async call? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593001/679553

Comment: @GazihanAlankus What do you mean? Are you asking why i have the else statement?

Comment: or are you saying to just ignore it entirely?

Comment: Yes I'd say ignore it. This happens in an async call after the widget is unmounted. This async function is not supposed to continue anyway. I think if(mounted) can even be harmful as it lets the function continue to work after the widget is unmounted. You could return from this one, but its caller continues to execute. The exception successfully gets rid of this async call for good. I just ignore these.

Comment: In my case the setState is being called inside of a timer. If I ignore it the console gets flooded with the exception messages. I'm able to use the extension function I made to stop the timer if its not mounted `setStateIfMounted(() => currentIndex++, () => timer.cancel());`

Comment: Although as I'm writing that I'm realizing it should probably be stopped in onDispose

Comment: Oh I see. I don't use timers but I think I would make everything explicit to avoid possible issues.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create an abstract class that extends `State` and overrides `setState(...)`.

```
abstract class SafeState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    super.setState(fn);
  }
}
```

In your `StatefulWidget`'s state, extend `SafeState` instead of `State`.